# How to add a line with remove button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok... This has been haunting me for days.

What I was trying to do is devoloping a page who adds dynamically what the user inputs in the text bar and close to the text there must a "remove" button who should remove that line. However I can only make the button remove the button itself, but not the line.

Here is the Add code:

```
$("#Add").click(function() {
    var $li = $("#test").val() + '<li>   <button class="Remove" type="button">Remove</button> </li>' ;
    $("ul").append($li);

        });
```

The Remove code:

```
$('ul').on('click', '.Remove', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();

});
```

And the body:

```
<ul></ul>
<button id="Add" type="button">Add</button>
<input type="text" id="test" value=""> <br>
```

I guess the easiest way to fix this would be adding the user input into the li /li body, but I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: `$("#test").val() + '<li>.......</li>'` will generate invalid HTML, As `ul` can have only have `li` as child

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xszbpqjr/1/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending value before `li` is generating invalid html elements.The jQuery code is working because it removes only the `<li>...</li>` and not the prepended text in your case : `User input <li>...</li>`.

The text should be inside `li` (innertext).

Change

```
var $li = $("#test").val() + '<li>   <button class="Remove" type="button">Remove</button> </li>' ;
```

to

```
var $li = '<li><button class="Remove" type="button">Remove</button>'+ $("#test").val() +'</li>';
```

Comment: oh god... it just worked! cannot believe it was this simple. thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
$("#Add").click(function() {
  var $li = '<li> ' + $("#test").val() + '  <button class="Remove" type="button">Remove</button> </li>';
  $("ul").append($li);

});
```